# Is there any way to increase my Unity sprite's quality?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

As title, sprite quality is too low on game mode but it is fine on Scene mode. The texture is fine. I look for solutions on the internet, change filter mode, max size, compression but nothing change.

- gamemode: https://imgur.com/a/VLedm3c
- scene mode: https://imgur.com/a/OKItcSa
- texture inspector: https://imgur.com/a/AsuC9hg

Comment: well the texture inspector says the original texture only is `299 x 740` .. increasing the maxsize etc settings has no effect whatsoever if your texture simply doesn't have a better quality ;)